# If, elif, and else conditions are not working correctly in my code

Tags: python, conditional-operator

```
def greeting(string):
    greet=["Good Morning"+' '+string]
    return(greet)

print("Enter your name")
name=input()

if(name is "Saptarshi"):
    greet=greeting(name)
    print(greet)

elif(name is "Gurpreet"):
    greet=greeting(name)
    print(greet)

else:
    print("No greeting for you!")
```

Comment: Can you provide your input? Also, why are you using `is`? You should use `==`

Comment: whether you use 'is' or '==' its the same thing because both serve as conditional expressions. I tried with '==' first, but it didn't work so I changed it to 'is', but even then it is not working. You can try running the code yourself, and see if it works

Comment: Well your code isn't properly formatted according to PEP8 so it doesn't make it easy to use

Comment: You are returning greet before getting to the if statements

Comment: @saptarshi, no, `is` and `==` are definitely _not_ the same in Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/354577

Comment: Why are you using conditionals in the first place? The body is the same for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` instead of is.

Python `is` operator compares two variables and returns `True` if they reference the same object. If the two variables reference different objects, the `is` operator returns False.

```
a = 100
b = a
result = a is b # True

d = 10
e = 10
result = d is e # False
```

Comment: So what I said in my comment.